# regex not matching spaces on text between parentheses

Tags: php, regex

Why doesn't this regex match white space on text between parentheses?
`\((?:(\(\s>)|(\s{2,})|(\s\)))\)`

The text below it that isn't enclosed in parenthesis should be ignored. It's just there. No need to worry with that. Only the ones in parentheses need to be touched.

```
(  R:2379; L:  28 ) //replace to (R:2379;L:28)
R:2379;L:28
(R:2432;L:28) // ok, no replacements needed
R:2432; L:28
( R  :  2475; L:    28   ) // replace to (R:2475;L:28)
R:2475; L:28
(     R : 2480   ; L:28 ) // replace to (R:2480;L:28)
R:2480; L:28
```

Edit:

```
(  R:2379; L:  28 ) //replace to (R:2379; L:28) #a single space is ok, except before or after a parentheses. Multiple spaces are reduced to blank.
(R:2432;L:28) // ok, no replacements needed
(R:2432; L: 28) // ok, no replacements needed. The single spaces are not before or after the parentheses
( R  :  2475; L:    28   ) // replace to (R:2475; L:28) #the single space before the L is fine. other multiple spaces are blanked
(     R : 2480   ; L: 28 ) // replace to (R:2480; L: 28) #the single space before the 28 is fine
```

Comment: In PHP, to replace all spaces in between parentheses is either `preg_replace_callback('/\([^()]*\)/', function ($m) { return preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $m[0]); }, $string)`, or `preg_replace('/(?:\G(?!\A)|\()[^()]*?\K\s+(?=[^()]*\))/', '', $string)`

Comment: Sorry, I should have used the word `match` not `replace`

Comment: Yes, same. `{2,}`

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind the last example? `(     R : 2480   ; L: 28 ) // replace to (R:2480; L: 28) #the single space before the 28 is fine`. Why not keep single spaces on both sides of `:`? They are single spaces.

Comment: Sure no problem. The space before the `L` is fine and the space before the `28` is also fine. I should have mentioned that in the edit. The space before the `)` will be replaced with a `''`

Comment: Well, it is so unclear now, I am not sure I can help you more unless you provide a clear set of requirements. Here is the [last pattern](https://regex101.com/r/fMncvn/4), it matches whitespaces right after `(` and right before `)`, and only two or more whitespace chunks only inside parentheses.

Comment: I think the last one did it... Not sure. Only a bit of testing will tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_replace('/(?:\G(?!\A)|\()[^()]*?\K(?:(?<=\()\s+|\s+(?=\))|\s{2,})(?=[^()]*\))/', '', $string)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fMncvn/4). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\()`  - either the end of the previous match or `(`
- `[^()]*?` - zero or more chars other than `(`, `)`, as few as possible
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `(?:(?<=\()\s+|\s+(?=\))|\s{2,})` - 1+ whitespaces right after `(`, or 1+ whitespaces right before `(`, and any two or more whitespace characters
- `(?=[^()]*\))` - that are followed with any 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)`.

Comment: Can the `{2,}` part be left as it is?

Comment: @jmenezes Then, it won't give you expected result, see `(?:\G(?!\A)|\()[^()]*?\K\s{2,}(?=[^()]*\))` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fMncvn/2).

Comment: One space is ok except if that space is before a `(` or `)`. That's why I used three `|`

Comment: So, `(?:\G(?!\A)|\(\s+)[^()]*?\K\s{2,}+(?!\))(?=[^()]*\))`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fMncvn/3).

Comment: I meant there should not be any trailing space after a `(` or before a `)`. A single space anywhere else is ok to have.

Comment: @jmenezes Can you please edit the question to clarify what you mean?

Comment: One small question, if i need to match symbols other than `(` `)`, say if I needed `[` & `]` or `{` & `}` where would I need to make changes in your regex?

Comment: @jmenezes Right where `(` and `)` are. Just replace `(` with `[` or `{` and `)` with `]` or `}`